If a group has exactly two elements of the same order, the order is only 3, 4, or 6

Let $G$ be a group with exactly two elements $a,b$ of order $n$, where $n\not\in\{1,2\}$. Prove that $n\in\{3,4,6\}$.

I have shown that $\langle a\rangle = \langle b\rangle$, and that $\langle a\rangle \trianglelefteq G$. I assume the next step is to use something related to the Orbit-Stabiliser theorem or Lagrange's theorem, but in this problem $G$ is not necessarily finite. How may I approach this problem further?

This follows from the following:
Fact 1: $\langle a\rangle$ has $\varphi(n)$ elements of order $n$.
Fact 2: If $\varphi(n)=2$ then $n=3,4,6$.

Just completing the answer: The set of elements of order $n$ has cardinality $0$ or cardinality $\ge\phi(n)$.
